# Uncaught TypeError: Viewport is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I am trying to set a simple exemple of [pixi-viewport](https://github.com/davidfig/pixi-viewport). It works fine with Pixi.js but even thought the script for pixi-viewport is found (viewport.js) I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Viewport is not a constructor

Here's the HTML file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Pixi</title>
</head>
<script src="pixi/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="pixi/viewport.js"></script>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let Application = PIXI.Application,
            loader = PIXI.loader,
            resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
            Sprite = PIXI.Sprite;
            Graphics = PIXI.Graphics

        //Create a Pixi Application
        let app = new Application({
            width: 953,
            height: 409,
            backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
        });

        const viewport = new Viewport({
            screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
            screenHeight: window.innerHeight,
            worldWidth: 1000,
            worldHeight: 1000,

            interaction: app.renderer.plugins.interaction // the interaction module is important for wheel to work properly when renderer.view is placed or scaled
        })

        // add the viewport to the stage
        app.stage.addChild(viewport)

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that since Pixi v5, the direct access to window.Viewport has been pulled out.

You need to use some sort of build system (like parcel, rollup, webpack, etc.). That will let you pull the libraries in from npm and make your life easier.